# accessing variables from top level package

Tags: python

I have the following structure -

```
invoize/
    __init__.py
    globals.py
    view/
       __init__.py
       tags.py
```

globals.py contains a variable called app.

1. I would like to access that variable from tags.py.
2. I would like modify it so that its state gets reflected globally ( not just a local reference).

How do I access the variable *app* from tags.py to achieve the above ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: define _state gets reflected globally_ ...

Answer (score 4):

Use a [relative import](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html):

```
from ..invoize import globals
print globals.app
globals.app = True
```

Note that for this to work:

1. You'll need an `__init__.py` in the top level, alongside `view` and `invoize`
2. You'll need to import `tags` from outside the package (you won't be able to go into the `view` folder and run `python tags.py`.

Comment: This is the error I receive - File "/home/murtaza/workspace/flask/invoize/view/tags.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..invoize import globals
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Comment: Did you include the `__init__.py` file next to `invoize` and `view`, and import it from outside the package?

Comment: I have done edits in the folder structure shown in the question. I have __init__.py in both the folders. And am trying to import a model in the parent package from the child package. Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried editing the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the "/invoize/" dir?

Here is how I went about your question:

[gp@imdev1 /testdir/invoize/view] export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/testdir/

[gp@imdev1 /testdir/invoize/view] echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/selenium/webdriver/support/:/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/selenium/webdriver/ie/:/testdir/

In /testdir/invoize/globals.py:

```
app = 'murtaza52'
```

In /testdir/invoize/view/tags.py:

> import invoize.globals
>
> print invoize.globals.app
>
> invoize.globals.app += ' newvalue'
>
> print invoize.globals.app

[gp@imdev1 /testdir/invoize/view]$ python tags.py

murtaza52

murtaza52 newvalue